# Is Google Analytics Part Of Google's Search Engine Algorithm

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search, search-results

I was wondering if anyone knows if Google uses the data it receives from Google Analytics to help determine a websites SERP (Search Engine Rank Position). For example, if my website is getting 1000 users visiting my website from Canada and only 100 users visiting my website from the USA, does that mean my website will be ranked higher on Google.ca and lower on Google.com? And, if a website is using Google Analytics will it be ranked higher for the organic search engine keywords?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> "To the best of my knowledge, it does not."

– Matt Cutts, Google employee, answering [Does Google Analytics play a part in SERPs?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZoesvNUPDQ) via video.